# Sub príncipe dúró temporibusque malís audés esse bonus

Tags: wheelocks-latin

In page 46, sententiae antíquae, sententia numerus sextus

> Sub príncipe dúró temporibusque malís audés esse bonus

My guess is that this means

> Under bad times and strict chief you hear being good.

But I am very dubious abut the *esse bonus* part of the sentence.

Answer (score 6):

*Audes* is the 2nd person singular of *audeo*, not *audire*. It means "to dare", not "to hear."

*Esse* is the complementary infinitive of *audes*, so you should translate it more strictly with *to* ***X***: you dare *to be* good.

Just a side note, *principe* here refers to the Roman emperor, whose formal title was *princeps*. Translating it as "chief" might be correct in some contexts, but not the one where this comes from (adapted from Martial *Epigrams* 12.3). From Augustus onward, that word, virtually wherever it is found, comes highly loaded with political connotations.

Comment: Still does not solve my problem with *esse bonus*

Comment: @Dolphínus I'm not sure how much more explicit he can be than by telling you than *audes esse* means "dare to be"

Comment: @brianpck I am a true idiot

Comment: This adapted form of the sentence is from Wheelock's Latin (just FYI).